# How do I include sourced code into a function in R?

Tags: r, function

I have a function I wrote and saved in a .R file.
I want to source the code in another .R file while modifying it.

For example, What I want is:

file1 code :

```
func <- function(x=x) {sum(x)}
```

file2 code:

```
func2 <- function(x) {source('file1.R')}
func2(x=c(2:3))
[1] 5
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As an alternative, if you're sourcing files inside other functions, it might be time to start moving these things to a package.

Answer (score 3):

Try `source("file1.R", local=TRUE)`. This will make the evaluation happen within the scope of the function rather than (the default behavior) the scope of the workspace.

But, as you currently have it written, it still won't work because your `file1` is defining a function but not evaluating it.

To achieve the behavior you want, you'll want something like:

```
## file1.R ##
s <- sum(x)

## file2.R ##
func2 <- function(x) {
    source("file1.R", local=TRUE)
    return(s)
}
func2(x=c(2,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that a significant advantage of these solutions is that they don't re-read file1.R each time `func2` runs.

**1) source into workspace**  The source call will define func and then we define `func2` to be the same as `func` and finally we optionally remove `func`.  At this point we can run `func2`.

```
source('file1.R')
func2 <- func
rm(func) # optional
func2(x=c(2:3))
```

**2) source into local environment** An alternative would be to source the file defining `func` in a local environment  and assign the last statement in the local environment to `func2`; however, `func2` itself is outside the local environment.  After the definition of `func2`, `func` will not be visible but `func2` will be.  Note that the `source` statement is only run once and only `func` is assigned to `func2` so that the `source` statement is not run each time `func2` is run.

```
func2 <- local({
    source("file1.R", local = TRUE)
    func
})
func2(x=c(2:3))
```

**3) modules package**

After installing the modules package from [github](https://github.com/klmr/modules) (this package gives you something half way between `source` and full R packages) try this:

```
# devtools::install_github('klmr/modules')

library(modules)

file1 <- import("file1")
func2 <- file1$func
func2(3:4)
```

**Note:** that in the question's definition of `func` in file1.R that the argument `x=x` will generate an error if `x` is not supplied by the caller since it will result in a self reference.  What is really wanted is: `func <- function(x) sum(x)` or even just `func <- sum`.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, your code creates a function which sources 'file1.R' regardless of the x input.  You need to tell the function to run the old function as well.

```
func2 <- function(x){
    source('file1.R',local=TRUE)
    func(x)
}
```